# Exit ANTLR Parsing

Tags: java, antlr

I've made some parser rules in an ANTLR grammar file that I want to use to flag an error and exit parsing, i.e., no need to continue parsing the input file/files.

Is there a mechanism to exit parsing in ANTLR when a particular parserCallback is triggered?

Comment: What `parserCallback`? Can you give an example?

Comment: throw an exception? take a look at the error strategy interface.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was trying to find.